# linear programming formulation

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

I want to formulate equations for this problem. I have previously looked at many [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3211618/mixed-integer-programming-formulation-for-n-jobs-on-m-machines-with-preceding-co) and I am new to this.

Suppose I have n total fruit plantations and s number of just apple plantations.

I want to place s and (n-s) plantations on an m by m grid of field.

The objective function should be minimizing the area of the grid field where n fruits are to be planted.

Also, I need to control the (n-s) plantations/grid points. That means for all the plantations except the apple plantations, I might place multiple plantations on the same grid point.

Please help.

Comment: Does "area" mean the number of grid points where at least one plantation is placed?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three sets of decision variables. Let binary variable $a_{i,j}$ indicate whether an apple plantation is placed at grid point $(i,j)$. Let nonnegative integer variable $b_{i,j}$ be the number of non-apple fruit plantations placed at $(i,j)$. Let binary variable $f_{i,j}$ indicate whether at least one fruit plantation is placed at $(i,j)$. The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i,j} f_{i,j}$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} &= s \tag1\\
\sum_{i,j} b_{i,j} &= n-s \tag2\\
a_{i,j} &\le f_{i,j} &&\text{for all $i,j$} \tag3\\
b_{i,j} &\le (n-s) f_{i,j} &&\text{for all $i,j$} \tag4\\
b_{i,j} &\le (n-s) (1 - a_{i,j}) &&\text{for all $i,j$} \tag5
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ places all $s$ apple plantations.
Constraint $(2)$ places all $n-s$ non-apple plantations.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $a_{i,j}=1 \implies f_{i,j}=1$.
Constraint $(4)$ enforces $b_{i,j}>0 \implies f_{i,j}=1$.
Constraint $(5)$ enforces $a_{i,j}=1 \implies b_{i,j}=0$.

Comment: I need to minimize f_i,j for the minimizing area constraint. I have some rough ideas for the rest. It would be good for my personal development to read a descriptive solution to this problem from an experienced person like you.

Comment: I added the details now.  Can you predict the optimal objective value?

Comment: Thank you very much. I could not predict (5) at all. I am not being successful to predict optimal objective value either.

Comment: Each apple plantation needs its own point, and all the rest of the plantations can be placed together in one additional point.

Comment: For the rest of the plantations can it be controlled? Like, say 5 plantations for the rest of the plantations/grid point?

Comment: If you want to limit the non-apples to 5 plantations per grid point, change the $(n-s)$ in constraint $(4)$ to 5.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on equations (3), (4), (5)..I thought I understood why enforcing those constraints is necessary but I don't ...Thanks a lot..

Comment: Without (3), you could have $a_{i,j}=1$ and $f_{i,j}=0$, which would mean that you place an apple plantation at $(i,j)$ without paying for it in the objective.  Constraint (4) is similar for non-apple plantations. Without (5), you could place both apple and non-apple plantations at the same grid point.