# Linear programming formulation confusion

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have a silly confusion.

For this constraint [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814154/constraints-formulation-extended),  $a_{i1,j1} + a_{i2,j2} ≤ 1$  if  $0 < |i1−i2|+|j1−j2| < d$.

I understand this constraint but I want to ensure that this encompasses all $i$ and $j$, not just $i1,i2$, and $j1,j2$. I am told that this constraint in fact, encompasses ALL $i$ and $j$, but I am **NOT** getting it.

Also, can we have 'if' in a programming constraint equation like this? I am trying to find an example but failing at that.

Please help.

Comment: Hi,
Could you please Latex rendering allowed by mathjax?
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
This will make your post a lot more readable.

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not one constraint, but rather a set of constraints, one for each $(i_1, i_2, j_1, j_2)$ satisfying the condition  $0 < |i_1 - i_2| + |j_1 - j_2| < d$.  The "if" clause is not part of the linear programming problem itself, it just determines what constraints that problem has.

Comment: How do I generalize it for all i,j in accordance with linear programming rules? Including the 'if' is normal for expressing problems like these as I didn't see examples with 'if' in the constraints anywhere? Please help.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that this is already generalized? Could you please elaborate how?

Comment: The "if" is actually be used as shorthand for "for all $i_1, i_2, j_1, j_2$ such that $0 < |i_1 -i_2| + |j_1 - j_2| < d$.

Comment: What do you mean by "generalized"?  Do you want the constraint for all $i_1, i_2, j_1, j_2$?

Comment: I want for all i  and j that means $i_{1}$,$i_{2}$,$i_{3}$........$i_{n}$ and $j_{1}$,$j_{2}$,$j_{3}$........$j_{n}$ ..Thank you.

Comment: @prubin But how do I include the other constraint then...? This one:   a_{i1,j1}+a{i2,j2}≤1.......without the **if**

Comment: So you say "for all $i_1$, $i_2$, $j_1$, $j_2$".